# Haskell: Find element using XML.Light

Tags: xml, haskell

Quite new to Haskell. I'm trying to parse the following XML using the Text.XML.Light package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfInt xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.chemspider.com/">
  <int>395443</int>
</ArrayOfInt>
```

At the moment I'm just trying to grab the `<int>` element. I have the following code:

```
parseServerResponse = map (findChild (unqual "int")) . onlyElems . parseXML
```

And I'm passing the xml as a string. I've tried all sorts of variations but with no success. All I get back is the list: `[Nothing,Nothing]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to run your example myself before I got it.

The `xmlns="http://www.chemspider.com/"` sets the XML namespace for all elements that do not have an explicit prefix.

So, the qualified name of that `<int>395443</int>` isn't `unqual "int"`.  Instead it is: `QName {qName = "int", qURI = Just "http://www.chemspider.com/", qPrefix = Nothing}`

Try this:

```
parseServerResponse = String -> [Element]
parseServerResponse = filterElementsName (("int" ==) . qName) <=< onlyElems . parseXML
```

Using `(<=<)` from Control.Monad.  That's a "backwards" Kleisli fish.